# How to use generic type inheritance in csharp

Tags: c#, templates, generics, inheritance

I have this sample summy generic code:

```
public class Box<E> where E : BoxProperties{
}

public class BoxProperties{
}

public class BlueBox : Box<BlueBox.BlueProperties >{
    public class BlueProperties : Properties{
    }
}

public class RedBox : Box<RedBox.RedProperties >{
    public class RedProperties : Properties{
    }
}
```

I need to create a Dictionary that can store RedBox and BlueBox as values.
Any help please?

Comment: `BlueProperties` and `RedProperties` inherits from Properties so simply create a `Dictionary<TKey, Properties>`.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria That will not help him store `RedBox` or `BlueBox` objects.  Neither `RedBox` nor `BlueBox` inherit from `Properties`.

Comment: @cdhowie you're right I did not understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
public class BoxProperties
{
}
interface IBox
{

}

public class Box<E> : IBox where E : BoxProperties
{
}

public class BlueBox : Box<BlueBox.BlueProperties>
{
    public class BlueProperties : BoxProperties
    {
    }
}

public class Properties
{
}

public class RedBox : Box<RedBox.RedProperties>
{
    public class RedProperties : BoxProperties
    {
    }
}
```

With this you will be able to do -

```
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IBox>();
        dictionary.Add("a", new BlueBox());
        dictionary.Add("b", new RedBox());
```

Comment: That turned out to be the right solution for my problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

With the types as you have described them, the nearest common ancestor type between `BlueBox` and `RedBox` is `System.Object`.  You will have to use a `Dictionary<TKey, object>`, or introduce some other common ancestor type.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what is the class `Box<E>`

```
interface IBox<out E> where E : BoxProperties
{
}

public class Box<E> : IBox<E> where E : BoxProperties
{
}

public class BoxProperties
{
}

public class BlueBox : Box<BlueBox.BlueProperties>
{
    public class BlueProperties : BoxProperties
    {
    }
}

public class RedBox : Box<RedBox.RedProperties>
{
    public class RedProperties : BoxProperties
    {
    }
}
```

With this you can declare a dictionary like:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, IBox<BoxProperties>>();

dic.Add("red", new RedBox());
dic.Add("blue", new BlueBox());
```

But the `out` cannot be best for you, take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Comment: +1. I hope this is the chosen answer, is by far the best approach

Comment: It depends on the design of the class, the `out` is restrictive.